# Programmatically updating w. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

We currently have a system setup that gives each type of work a 3-letter "code". I was able to wrestle a little bit with management about moving them to an int value so I can autopopulate and run with a uniqueidentifier. So they're on board with that now.

Current table:

```
tblWorkID
WorkID: [3 digit keys]
```

What I would like/need is to `Update` all the WorkID keys into an `int` value, ascending. This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT distinct WorkID
from tblWorkID
order by WorkID
```

Any idea how I can put the logic in there to create a running number based off that data or am I trying to do too much with the SQL? It's 482 total entries and I'd rather not do that by hand (but will if needbe.)

Like this: (Data shown)

```
AAA Apple Picking
AAB Construction
AAC General Cleaning
```

And have it populate to something like this:

```
1 Apple Picking
2 Construction
3 General Cleaning
```

(Disregard the text next to the numbers and letter sequences, I put it in there for explanation.)

Update: What I currently have is WorkID: [3-letter sequence] is just another field added into the WorkID table (WorkHrs, WorkContact, WorkContract, etc.) So there are multiple WorkID's of say, AAA and AAC within the table--the data integrity is very very well, cloudy.

Update2: My current table structure is like this (I'll be adding in another ID uniqueidentifier field soon):

```
tblWorkID
WorkId
WorkHrs
WorkContact
WorkContractID
WorkMgrID
WorkDetails
```

Comment: Are you wanting to change the datatype of the column, or add a new Identity column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:
Based on your comment below (and some assumptions...) I think you can use DENSE_RANK instead of row_number:

```
 SELECT DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY <your 3 letter code>,
```

That way, all instances of the same three letter code will get the same number.

If I understand you, you can use the [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)() function to generate your running number:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <your 3 letter code>,
...
```

Or, depending on your current table structure, you may be able to just add an [identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) column.

```
ALTER TABLE <Your Table>
ADD <NEW COLUMN NAME> Identity(1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you, but since different records are tied to the WorkID how would I ensure they remain "linked?"

Comment: Modified my answser, see if that's what you meant.

Comment: Ok so I have this: `SELECT DENSE_RANK () OVER (ORDER BY WorkID) from tblWorkID` Which houses the correct information, now how/where would I put the update statement?

Comment: Do you have an existing column you want to put it in?

Comment: Essentially to do an update and replace the existing WorkID field with the new value.

Comment: I'd really suggest adding a new column, much safer, leaves you some sort of audit trail, etc.

Comment: Alright thanks. But how would I add in the new column? As this is a new function to me I don't want to mess it up. :) The insert goes after the `WorkID)` part I'm assuming?

Comment: Wait so you're saying just do the Alter statement? But I need the values from the previous statement to be the values for the new column.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out. I did a join update. :) All's working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Create an ID per WorkID

```
create table T (id int identity(1,1), WorkID char(3))
    insert T select distinct WorkID from thetable order by WorkID asc
```

Update the existing

```
update thetable set WorkID = (select id from T where T.WorkID = thetable.WorkID)
```

Change the column type to INT.

Comment: Appreciate your time.